# CakePHP 3: How to make assoc with one record?

Tags: php, cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.0, model-associations

I wanna make assoc with Locations via locations_ways join table what contain order and point (start / middle / end) of way.

In end I wanna get assoc
locations - all locations
end_location ONLY end location
start_location ONLY start location

Now for end_location and start_location I have array what containe one record. But I dont want write some like this: $way->end_location[0]->name;

How to process it?

```
class WaysTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
         $this->belongsToMany('Locations', [
            'through' => 'LocationsWays',
            'sort' => ['LocationsWays.position ASC'],
        ]);
        $this->belongsToMany('LocationStartPoint', [
            'className' => 'Locations',
            'foreignKey' => 'way_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'location_id',
            'through' => 'LocationsWays',
            'conditions' => ['LocationsWays.point' => 'start'],
        ]);
        $this->belongsToMany('LocationEndPoint', [
            'className' => 'Locations',
            'foreignKey' => 'way_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'location_id',
            'through' => 'LocationsWays',
            'conditions' => ['LocationsWays.point' => 'end'],
        ]);
    }
}

class LocationsTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->belongsToMany('Ways', [
            'through' => 'LocationsWays',
        ]);
    }
}

class LocationsWaysTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->belongsTo('Ways', [

        ]);
        $this->belongsTo('Locations', [

        ]);
    }
}
```

Fetching func.

```
public function getWayById($id, $locale = 'uk')
    {
        I18n::locale($locale);

        $item = $this->find()
            ->where(['Ways.id' => $id])
            ->contain(['Locations', 'LocationStartPoint', 'LocationEndPoint'])
            ->cache(function (Query $q) {
                return 'way-' . md5(serialize($q->clause('where')));
            }, 'orm')
            ->first();

        return $item;
    }
```

Comment: Please show your code where you're fetching data.

Comment: Added.to first post.

Comment: Your question is very hard to read, especially the second paragraph, you may want to rephrase it and use some punctuation. Also a proper example of what _exactly_ you'd expect the resulting data structure to look like would be very helpful. Also please make sure that you use actual names, given your association configuration, there is no such property named `end_location`. If this stems from somewhere else, then please mention that and show the relevant code.